# Required validando propriedade de outro objeto

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, entity-framework

Tenho as seguintes propriedades, porém quando vou validar via ModelState.IsValid retorna que que a descrição do grupo de usuário de ser informada que é  UsuarioId também, mas o problema é que estou solicitando para o proprio banco gerar a chave. Como faço para não apresentar essas inconsistências?
GrupoDeUsuario esta sendo preenchido com uma DropdownList.

```
     [Key]
     [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
      public int UsuarioId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Nome do usuário deve ser informado")]
    public string UsuarioDeAcesso { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Senha do usuário deve ser informada")]
    public string SenhaDeAcesso { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Grupo deve ser selecionado")]
    public int GrupoDeUsuarioId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Grupo deve ser selecionado")]
    public GrupoDeUsuario GrupoDeUsuario { get; set; }
```

Comment: Uma forma que achei foi utilizar  this.ModelState.Remove("UsuarioId"); mas acho que para este caso não é o mais indicado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não use isto:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Grupo deve ser selecionado")]
public GrupoDeUsuario GrupoDeUsuario { get; set; }
```

Propriedades de navegação são entes complexos. Você deve manter apenas esta validação abaixo preenchida, até porque este é o elemento importante da validação, e não o objeto dependente:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Grupo deve ser selecionado")]
public int GrupoDeUsuarioId { get; set; }
```

Comment: Funcionou, estou acostumado com NHibernate, essas propriedades de navegação é novidade para mim. Mas como faço para não validar o UsuarioId? no cadrastro ele deve ser 0 mesmo mas na alteração deve ser informado.

Comment: O segredo é usar `IValidatableObject`. Faça outra pergunta que te digo como.